# Bing Map Drawing Tool Module - events

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm using Bing Map Ajax Control V7 for test / learning.
I created a few pushpins with infobox, and added events:

```
function InsertEvent(mark, infoBox)
      {
        var obj = {marker : {}, infoWind : {}};
        obj.marker.entity = mark;  
        obj.marker.eID = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(mark, "click", function(e) {toggleInfo(e, infoBox, true)});

        obj.infoWind.entity = infoBox;
        obj.infoWind.eID = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(infoBox, "mouseleave", function(e) {toggleInfo(e, infoBox, false)});
        eventsID.push(obj);
      }
```

So, these events work well, until I add DrawningToolModule to map.

```
function GetMap()
      {  

         map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), 
            {credentials: "My extra top secret Bing Map Key",
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.201547622680664, 16.16974449157715), zoom: 15 });

         Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', { callback: searchModuleLoaded });

         Microsoft.Maps.registerModule("DrawingToolsModule", "DrawingToolsModule/DrawingToolsModule.js");
         Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("DrawingToolsModule", { callback: function () {
                drawTools = new DrawingTools.DrawingManager(map, {toolbarContainer : document.getElementById("toolbarContainer")});
            }
         });
      }
```

After loading data, pushpins reaction on click is fine.
After adding custom pushpins by DrawingTool - events are fine.
After drawing any shape (polygon, polyfil, circle) - my events for pushpins aren't invoking.

I added a function helper to check if event is still available:

```
function showEventsCount()
      {
         alert("Registered events: " + eventsID.length + "\nFirst entity has click event: " +
              Microsoft.Maps.Events.hasHandler(eventsID[0].marker.entity, "click") /*map.entities.getLength()*/);
      }
```

And in result I get true.

Is this a bug with blocking events, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely issue is that your polygon is above your pushpins thus blocking the click event or there is an issue. Alternatively there is an EntityCollection above the pushpins that has the polygons in them. This is a known issue with Bing Maps v7. Try flatting the way the map renders polygons with the following code:

```
map.getMode().setOptions({drawShapesInSingleLayer: true });
```

Comment: what is the alternate for this in bing maps v 8 ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: map.getMode(...).setOptions is not a function. 
This code is for version 7 of bing maps . it has been deprecated in v8.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529976.aspx

Comment: What I meant is that this function doesn't exist in V8 as the control now does this by default. The V8 control handles rendering in a completely different way that V7. All shapes are rendered into one of two HTML5 canvases. Where as in V7 where each shape was it's own SVG.